# Getting a 403 AccessDenied uploading a file to S3 only when using public-read ACL

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

I'm trying to do a POST of image data (direct from the browser using JavaScript). If I use a `private` ACL everything works but if I change it to `public-read` I get a 403 response with the message `AccessDenied`.

- The `acl` attribute in my policy matches the `acl` form parameter I'm sending.
- I'm definitely getting past the authentication stage as if I deliberately screw up the signature I get a `SignatureDoesNotMatch` response.
- As I say with a different ACL the upload works.

Any ideas what can cause this?

As requested here's the code I'm using (it will need some tidying up after I get it working):

```
.directive 's3ImageUploader', ['$http', '$filter', ($http, $filter) ->
  replace: true
  restrict: 'E'
  scope: true
  template: '<input type="file" name="image" class="form-control input-lg">'
  link: ($scope, $element) ->
    awsAccessKeyId = '...'
    secret = '...'
    bucket = '...'
    folder = '...'
    policy =
      expiration: '2020-12-01T12:00:00.000Z'
      conditions: [
        {bucket: bucket}
        ['starts-with', '$key', '']
        {acl: 'public-read'}
        ['starts-with', '$Content-Type', 'image/']
      ]
    policyBase64 = $filter('base64') policy
    signature = $filter('hmacSha1') policyBase64, secret

    $element.on 'change', ->
      file = $element.get(0).files[0]
      key = "#{folder}/#{new Date().getTime()}-#{file.name}"

      formData = new FormData()
      formData.append 'key', key
      formData.append 'acl', 'public-read'
      formData.append 'Content-Type', file.type
      formData.append 'AWSAccessKeyId', awsAccessKeyId
      formData.append 'policy', policyBase64
      formData.append 'signature', signature
      formData.append 'file', file

      $http.post "https://#{bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/", formData,
        headers:
          'Content-Type': `undefined`
        transformRequest: (data) -> data
]
```

Comment: Can you post your ACL?

Comment: It's an Angular directive written in CoffeeScript (sorry) attaching it to the question above.

Comment: I've tested the same code against a fresh bucket I set up using my own AWS account and it works fine so this is something to do with the configuration of the bucket that I'm trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the user whose credentials I was using needed to have a policy set to enable me to use `public-read`

Comment: Rob, I think the problem you had is the same I'm experiencing. Could you explain in more details about this user's credentials policy? Thanks in advance.